# Remove arrow that hide/show stock tools GUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have made `stock tools GUI` hidden by default on my application, also I have added a custom button that shows/hides it next to the `exporting` hamburguer menu. With that in mind I'd like to remove the little arrow that shows/hides the menu originally, I couldn't find any reference for that arrow in API or Documentation.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/remove-hideshow-arrow-9ojgt?file=/src/CustomGUIChart.js) is a working Demo.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Just brutally do querySelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the following to your `style.css`:

```
.highcharts-bindings-wrapper .highcharts-arrow-left { 
   display: none;
}
```

That should work if you just want to hide the arrows.